# Autodesk Forge - Isolating element: amount of transparency of others

Tags: autodesk-forge

When we isolate an element in a 3d view, is there anyway to control the amount of transparency of all the other elements? Say, change to 50% translucent?
Have I missed something obvious?
And can you do the same for 2d views?

Comment: I think you can achieve that setting the opacity of the material for all other fragIds but the one you want to isolate, I'm not sure about 2D and would need to research that

Answer (score 2):

I dug out the following code for you, it shows how to set all leaf nodes to 50% opacity by changing their material properties:

AutodeskNamespace("Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension");

```
function getLeafNodes(model, nodeId) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

    try{

      var leafIds = [];

      var instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree

      nodeId = nodeId || instanceTree.getRootId()

      function _getLeafNodesRec(id){

        var childCount = 0;

        instanceTree.enumNodeChildren(id,
          function(childId) {
            _getLeafNodesRec(childId)
            ++childCount
          })

        if(childCount == 0){
          leafIds.push(id)
        }
      }

      _getLeafNodesRec(nodeId)

      return resolve(leafIds)

    } catch(ex){

      return reject(ex)
    }
  })
}

function nodeIdToFragIds(model, nodeId) {

  var instanceTree = model.getData().instanceTree

  var fragIds = []

  instanceTree.enumNodeFragments(
    nodeId, (fragId) => {
      fragIds.push(fragId)
    });

  return fragIds
}


Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic = function (viewer, options) {

  Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.call(this, viewer, options);

  var _this = this;

  _this.load = function () {

    var fragList = viewer.model.getFragmentList()

    getLeafNodes(viewer.model).then((dbIds) => {

      dbIds.forEach((dbId) => {

        const fragIds = nodeIdToFragIds(
          viewer.model, dbId)

        fragIds.forEach((fragId) => {

          var material = fragList.getMaterial(fragId)

          if(material) {

            material.opacity = 0.5
            material.transparent = true
            material.needsUpdate = true
          }
        })
      })

      viewer.impl.invalidate(true, true, true)
    })


    return true;
  };

  _this.unload = function () {

    Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.unregisterExtension(
      "Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic");

    return true;
  };
};

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic.prototype =
  Object.create(Autodesk.Viewing.Extension.prototype);

Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic.prototype.constructor =
  Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic;

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension(
  "Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic",
  Autodesk.ADN.Viewing.Extension.Basic);
```

Some syntax requires ES6 transpiling. You can quickly paste the code there to test it: http://viewer.autodesk.io/node/gallery/#/extension-editor?id=560c6c57611ca14810e1b2bf

This works only for 3D, I'll see what we can do for 2D and update that topic.

Comment: Thanks Philippe - 2d look a bit harder?

Comment: There is no easy way to achieve that currently with the API for 2D, you may be able to do it by programming custom shaders, but we do not have a sample to help you. Those blog posts deal with using custom shaders on 3D models in the viewer, could be helpful if you are not familiar with shaders programming: http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/07/using-shaders-to-generate-dynamic-textures.html http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/08/ace-editor-for-threejs-shadermaterials-in-the-forge-viewer.html